# warning of automatic ban filter system is broken "danger of being blocked"

Tags: discussion

I got a message about my questions being of poor quality.

I have no deleted any of my questions.

Obviously the system has erred.

[Questions not well received when none have negative votes!](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3678/questions-not-well-received-when-none-have-negative-votes/3679#3679)

In the event that I do get an automatic ban is there any human overseer that can reverse it, and how would I go about that if banned?

Comment: Actually, there *is* [one deleted question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/51265/do-we-have-any-portraits-of-the-ramban-nachmonides-and-how-authentic-are-they) - an automated process deleted that one. Of the remaining 5, 2 have no votes and 2 have a single upvote.

Comment: @Oded I see the deleted question (which btw is similar to this highly voted one, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30731/is-this-the-chofetz-chaim  had zero votes. (But putting aside the question of the justification for the deletion of that question, which I know wouldn't be your area) By my count, of the remaining ones there are 4 questions not 5. And Of the 4, One has 4 votes. Two have one vote. And one has zero votes. That is not a bad record (and a moderator on the question I link to, agrees that is not a bad record)

Comment: There are five non-deleted questions on your profile on Judaism, not four. Two have no net votes. (I don't see why that would trigger the warning though.)

Comment: @Mat  the last non-deleted question was posted after the warning. So i'm looking at the ones prior to the warning appeared, and i'm saying the warning is obviously an error. Though it'd be an error even it'd have been after the 5 non deleted questions.